# How to make async become sync

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm still trying to figure out how the async/await works.

```js
function func1() {
   console.log('a');
   func2();
   console.log('b');
}

async function func2() {
   console.log('1');
   let value = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function() { resolve('async') } , 2000));
   console.log(value)
   console.log('2');
}

func1();
```

How can I achieve output as below?

```
a
1
async
2
b
```

I try to make func2 as async and await the setTimeout, but then they whole func2 become async function.  So it will print out this instead:

```
a
1
b    
async
2
```

Comment: you can't make async become sync, because it's impossible - but you can get the ouptut you need

Comment: You need to `await func2()`. Whereby `func1` must become async too.

Comment: Sad :( i need to rethink my code then ..

Comment: see https://github.com/abbr/deasync. It clearly tells you why you might want to convert an async function into a sync function. Not highly recommended since it DOES block. But in a plain old script, why would that matter?

Answer (score 3):

You can't make async into sync

But you can get the output you need

make func1 async and use await

```js
async function func1() {
   console.log('a');
   await func2();
   console.log('b');
}

async function func2() {
   console.log('1');
   let value = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function() { resolve('async') } , 2000));
   console.log(value)
   console.log('2');
}

func1();
```

Comment: But then if there's one more upper level function, then I need to go all the way up .. This question just kinda explain my problem in general.. in my case, I cannot make everything become async :(

i have a function to store some value as cache, then 1 of the function to retrieve list of value , one of the value get from a function(from library i use) that is returning the json result in async. then it breaks all my other code :(

Comment: @Neo - asynchrony is like a virus ... it spreads quickly ... you can't beat it, you need to learn how to use it

Comment: @Neo “Async” means the value will be available *sometime later*. Synchronous code on the other hand works *right now*. Yes, if something becomes available *sometime later* and something else depends on it, it too must wait and that spreads all the way up.

Comment: ya, true. I forgot that it will be pushed to the end of stack by event loop.

Comment: @Neo It's not just that. The most typical async case is a network request to load data from a server. That could take several seconds, which is an eternity for your code to wait on. It can't just block and do nothing, it can still do a whole lot while that network request is in flight (e.g. react to user clicks). Just *when* that network response comes back, it must handle it then, and anything that depends on it must continue then and only then. That's the async execution model.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous means things are happening chronologically one after the other.
Asynchronous means things are happening chronologically independent of one another.

When you execute a task synchronously, you wait for it to finish before moving on to another task(one after the other).

When you execute a task asynchronously, you can move on to another task before the prior task finishes. But it can't be exactly guranteed.

So, in your code you've call an async function inside a sync funcion. So, accoding to above explanation, you can not gurantee that after calling async function func2() rest of the func1() will execute. Because func2() is an async funcation which you can't say how much time will it take l to end up its execution process. So, You can't make async become sync.

```
function func1() {
   console.log('a');
   func2(); // call a asyncronized method inside a syncronized method
   console.log('b');
}

async function func2() {
   console.log('1');
   let value = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function() { resolve('async') } , 2000));
   console.log(value)
   console.log('2');
  }
func1();
```

But you can call that async function func2() inside func1() using await keyword so at the same time func1() will need to convert into an async function in order to use await keyword. So, in this way your desired output can be generated.

```
// change func1() as async method
async function func1() {
   console.log('a');
   await func2(); // use await keyword
   console.log('b');
}

async function func2() {
   console.log('1');
   let value = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function() {resolve('async') } , 2000));
   console.log(value)
  console.log('2');
}

func1();
```

I hope that this will help you to understand the problem.